# UART 1.8V logic level translator

Tags: uart, level-shifting

In my circuit i need to make a possibility to connect 2.5, 3.3 and 5V UART interfaces to my 1.8V. Therefore i need to make logic level translation. I find this 1 channel chip [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1t45.pdf?ts=1629269155169&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN74LVC1T45%253FHQS%253DTI-null-null-octopart-df-pf-null-wwe), that convert logic levels up to 5V.
I have made next circuit: 1 chip is for RXD pin, and one pin, and one chip, that connect invertedly, is for TXD pin. It's correct?
[image]

Comment: It depends on the naming. Which side is TXD input from somewhere and which side is TXD output to somewhere? And same for RXD? If you disconnect XP7 you have floating inputs on those chips, and if you connect XP6 you are shorting two outputs together.

Comment: Input signal is on the left. I suppose to use XP6 connector if i need basic 1.8V uart, and XP7 if i need to convert levels

Comment: RXD and TXD on the left can't both be input signals. Please be more specific which one is input from somewhere and which one output to somewhere. And connecting XP7 will short two outputs together unless you remove the chips.

Comment: I have UART pins on my microcontroller and the left RXD signal comes from one of these pins through DA2, A to B. TXD, I assume, goes through the DA1 chip from an external uart.

Comment: So if RXD comes from the left it's an output? I still can't decipher for sure what you mean; which pin on the left is output from MCU to this circuit and which pin on the left is an input to MCU from this circuit?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I confused RXD and TXD in places. TXD is the pin for which the data goes from the MCU, and RXD is the pin for which the data goes to the MCU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting DIR to VCCB might damage the chip. DIR is referenced to VCCA.

Setting DIR to GND will buffer from B to A, so both buffers do the buffering into wrong direction.

And you can't connect two outputs together. Activating XP6 will connect 1.8V MCU TXD output to 5V buffer output.

Comment: The DIR inputs are overvoltage tolerant. Connecting to VCCB is a problem only if VCCB is lower than VCCA (e.g., powered off).